# Powershell SQL Query - Problem with a property "Site"

Tags: sql, powershell, dataset

I'm a beginner in powershell and SQL Query.  I figured out how to make a Query and i'm getting some results but i ran into a problem and don't know how to manage it.

My Code:

```
$dataSource = "MyBdServer"
$database = "DabaseName"
$connectionString = "Data Source=$dataSource; " + "Integrated Security=SSPI; " + "Initial Catalog=$database"
$connection = new-object system.data.SqlClient.SQLConnection($connectionString)
$sqlCommand = "select Site, Pavillon, Floor, Localisation, Description from [DabaseName].dbo.Local_C where Location_ID In ( '6096B3F168C546BE84A7A98C8210E947')"
$command = new-object system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand($sqlCommand,$connection)
$connection.Open()
$adapter = New-Object System.Data.sqlclient.sqlDataAdapter $command
$dataset = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$adapter.Fill($dataSet) | Out-Null
$connection.Close()
$dataSet.Tables
```

Output

```
Site         : NCH
Pavillon     : D
Floor        : Level S3
Localisation : D.S3.5113
Description  : CONSULT./ENTREVUE
```

The problem: when i'm trying to get the value by properties for site ($DataSet.Tables.Site) value is always empty, it works well with Pavillon, Floor, Localisation and Description.  I think it's because the Object System.Data.Dataset has a property with that name by default.  I'm trying to find a way to use this value.

Comment: Have you tried brackets or `"`? `Select [Site] ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`DataColumn`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn?view=net-6.0) has a [`Site`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.marshalbyvaluecomponent.site?view=net-6.0#system-componentmodel-marshalbyvaluecomponent-site) property which is why you're unable to reference the values of the `Site` column. There are two easy alternatives, the easiest one is to reference the `.Table` property of your `DataTable` and then the `.Site` property and the other alternative is to use the [`.ToTable(..)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataview.totable?view=net-6.0#system-data-dataview-totable(system-boolean-system-string())) method from [`DataView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataview?view=net-6.0).

```sh
$columns = @(
    'Site'
    'Pavillon'
    'Floor'
    'Localisation'
    'Description'
)

$dtt = [System.Data.DataTable]::new()
$columns | ForEach-Object{
    $dtt.Columns.Add([System.Data.DataColumn]::new($_))
}
$row = $dtt.NewRow()
$row.Site         = 'NCH'
$row.Pavillon     = 'D'
$row.Floor        = 'Level S3'
$row.Localisation = 'D.S3.5113'
$row.Description  = 'CONSULT./ENTREVUE'
$dtt.Rows.Add($row)

$dtt.Site       # => Doesn't work
$dtt.Table.Site # => Works

$dv = [System.Data.DataView]::new($dtt)
$dv.ToTable($true, 'Site') # => Works
```

Comment: Thanks you very much for de solutions and for the clear explanations!